# Best way to add/change 1 GET value while keeping others?

Tags: php

How can I make a link that justs adds or changes 1 GET var while maintaining all others?

I have a page that is created using different GET vars.

So it will be like `mypage.php?color=red&size=7&brand=some%20brand`

So I want to have a link that sets it to page=2 or size=8. Whats the easiest way to have a link do that without reseting all the other vars?

I hope that makes sense, let me know if I need to further explain anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse the url with [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the values of the url. You can then build a http query by using [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/http_build_query):

```
$query_arr = $_GET; //or parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_arr)
$query_arr["page"] = 2;
$query_arr["size"] = 8;

$query = http_build_query($query_arr);
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I mixed up the two functions ... its `parse_str()` of course.

Comment: Hi this "seems" like exactly what I need. However I don't think parse_query is a built in PHP function. I tried replacing it with parse_url but that just gives me an array of the different parts of the url (e.g. scheme, host, path, etc.)

Comment: OK I got it to work using your code but changing lines 1 and 2 to just $query_arr = $_GET

Answer (score 4):

[http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query)

Comment: also, parse_str.  Parse the querystring into an array with parse_star, alter only the keys you deem necessary, and then feed the array to http_build_query.  I've used this technique with success.

Comment: @Shrapnel: sometimes you want to manipulate a URL other than that of the currently requested page.  e.g., I used the above technique to add google analytics tracking tags to every URL in an html email.